# pt-table-checksum toolkit for few databases from file

Tags: mysql, percona, pt-table-checksum

I've got a question. I'm doing a simple script right now and it isn't working like I want.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cat /etc/backup.conf | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$|^--.*)" > /tmp/databases

    while read line; do
    pt-table-checksum [options] --databases $line --quiet
    done < /tmp/databases

    rm /tmp/databases
```

As you see I put names of databases to file /tmp/databases. Then I want to use pt-table-checksum for every database in that file line by line. This script works but only for first database name in file. Then it stops.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is more bash related than mysql related. Can you show an example of `/etc/backup.conf`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what is in backup.conf because my cat command works fine. In /tmp/databases I have someone like this:
database1
database2
database3
...
and I what to do pt-table-checksum command for every database line by line.

Comment: I know it sounds silly. Could you replace `pt-table-checksum ...` with a simple `echo $line` and run the script?

Comment: I did like you say and script works fine. I get my databases names line by line: mysql phpMyAdmin jabber dev_intranet dev_extranet ...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 'for' loop for this, which I have found easier to use for things like this. Often, either line break, spaces, or combinations of those can cause issues with your method.
Also, remove the `--quiet` from your command line to see the errors that pt-table-checksum may be reporting.

```
#!/bin/bash

for db in `cat /etc/backup.conf | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$|^--.*)"`
do
    pt-table-checksum [options] --databases $db --quiet
done
```

(Hope this reads ok, have answered on my phone!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but situation is similiar to while loop. There are no errors, script just do first loop with first database and then stops.

Comment: What you may find is that the DB list is presented as "db1 db2 db3" as a single line through the read line statement, and doesn't get split at the spaces, meaning the loop only runs once?

Comment: Is your DB list file set up with each database on a separate line, or with all databases on a single line?

Comment: When I do only cat command, DB list is presented as "db1 db2 db3" - each database on a separate line. I checked and there aren't any spaces at the beginning or at the end of each database name. It should be so simple but I have no idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: Check the file with `od -c filename` to see if there are any odd characters at the ends of the lines, indicating that they aren't separated with a line-feed. Can you `cat` the file and send a screenshot as an image perhaps?

Comment: I changed script a little bit. Now I check my all databases from file in one pt-table-checksum execution `percona=``egrep -v "^(#| *$|--|phpMyAdmin)" /etc/backup.conf | sed "s/$/,/g" | tr -d "\n" | xargs echo pt-table-checksum --set-vars innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50 --chunk-size-limit=0 --nocheck-plan --no-check-binlog-format --nocheck-replication-filters --user percona_check --host host --port port --quiet --databases``
$percona`